# Can I factorize a double sum into a product?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

Fix two positive constants $A,B>0$, two finite sets $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$, and two functions $\alpha,\beta \colon \mathcal A \times \mathcal B \to [0,1]$.

Assume that:

1. For all $b\in \mathcal B$, $\sum_{a\in\mathcal A} \alpha (a,b) \le A$.
2. For all $a\in \mathcal A$, $\sum_{b\in\mathcal B} \beta (a,b) \le B$.

Is it true that

$$\sum_{a\in\mathcal A} \sum_{b\in\mathcal B} \alpha (a,b) \beta (a,b) \le AB \ ?$$

This is one of those things that "feels" like it should hold (perhaps with some numerical constants like $2$ in front of $AB$) but I can neither prove nor disprove it.

The only simple observation that I could get so far is that by upper bounding $\alpha$ with $1$ and summing the $\beta$ (and vice-versa), it follows immediately that

$$\sum_{a\in\mathcal A} \sum_{b\in\mathcal B} \alpha (a,b) \beta (a,b) \le \min \bigl\{ A \cdot |\mathcal B|, \ B \cdot |\mathcal A| \bigr\}$$

This is, however, quite underwhelming because what if $A=B=1$, like in the case of $\alpha(\cdot,b)$ and $\beta(a,\cdot)$ that are probability distributions fora all $a,b$? Then $AB$ would be equal to $1$ but $\min \bigl\{ A \cdot |\mathcal B|, \ B \cdot |\mathcal A| \bigr\}$ would be huge if the underlying sets are big.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly not true. Consider the case where $\mathcal A=\mathcal B$, and let
$$
\alpha(a,b)=\beta(a,b)=\begin{cases}1&a=b\\0&a\neq b\end{cases}
$$
Then we can take $A=B=1$, yet we have $\sum_{\mathcal A}\sum_{\mathcal B}\alpha(a,b)\beta(a,b)=|\mathcal A|$, which can be arbitrarily larger than $1\times 1$.

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right, I am a dum-dum. :D